# Can I replace the larger fan in My Zotac NEN Steam Machine (ZBOX SN970)?

Tags: hardware-failure, fan, desktop-computer, repair

*Context: I used to build/upgrade my own desktop computers, so I'm fairly comfortable inside a case, but haven't worked in a pre-built "mini" computer before.*

I have an old Zotac NEN Steam Machine (model ZBOX SN970) that is still working great as a living room computer, but recently the larger of the two fans has started to rattle, and I'd like to replace it. I know it's the larger of the two fans that's noisy because I've opened the case up far enough to spin it with my finger and I can hear the sound. I believe the fan blades are hitting the top or bottom of the housing. Below are a few photos of the offending fan (in the widest shot, it's the one at the bottom of the image).

Questions:

1. Is this fan a standard part that I can order? It is 80mm wide by 80mm long (from the edge of the copper heat sink to the opposite end) by 19mm deep.
2. It looks to me like I can remove the existing fan by backing out the two screws holding it to the heat sink (top-left and bottom-right in the first image), unplugging the power cord, and peeling off the foil tape connecting it to the heat sink. Are there any other points of attachment I should expect?
3. About that foil tape, should I expect to be able to re-use the piece that's in there, or should I buy some? Is there a standard name/manufacturer for the tape?
4. Finally, it's not shown in the photos, but there's a small square antenna glued to the underside of the case top that's connected by a wire (without any plug/socket) to a wireless adapter on the motherboard. Can I expect to be able to unstick that antenna from the case (to get the case top out of the way) and then stick it back on when I'm done? Or is that likely to ruin the antenna? (And would I need a specific kind of glue to stick it back on, or would it likely still be sticky enough with the existing glue?)

You may notice that in one of the images, the fan looks pretty dusty. I did clean it (as shown in the other images) and it didn't help with the noise, so I believe it needs to be replaced -- but if you have other ideas, I'm interested!

[image: close up of noisy fan]

[image: wide shot of inside of Zotac NEN]

[image: medium shot of noisy fan]

Comment: This post is better suited for the [Hardware Recommendations SE site](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: looks exactly like the fan in my Dell Vostro 330.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, prior to posting, I did some research on where to ask hardware questions and [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57998/hardware-questions-and-stack-exchange) seems to think superuser is the right forum. The second answer in the linked post mentions Hardware Recommendations as being only for questions about _new_ hardware.

Comment: @mactyr Fair enough!

Comment: the 'foil' tape looks very much like  bog standard metal tape for ducting. Also the question about the wifi adaptor needs to be its own, with photos

Answer (score 0):

I emailed the manufacturer and they indicated that the fan is "[Laptop CPU Cooling Fan For TOSHIBA V000290220 6033B0029601 KSB0705HA-A BM1S 5V 0.60A](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256804572786164.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.23.4eac1b99lv9kUH&algo_pvid=cfef7c0d-b09a-417a-b14d-e64c32de6c96&algo_exp_id=cfef7c0d-b09a-417a-b14d-e64c32de6c96-11&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000030365591336%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21USD%2119.0%2118.05%21%21%21%21%21%40210217c716738925165681826d06bc%2112000030365591336%21sea&curPageLogUid=6gRsKA5ZvWSG)". I'm still interested in input on the other three sub-questions if anyone has it, otherwise I will update this answer if/when I make further discoveries.

UPDATE: I received my order of the fan listed above, but unfortunately it does not fit in the computer. The fan itself is slightly too large, and the power connector is too small. The fan I received has "6033B0043701" printed on it rather than the 6033B0029601 mentioned in the listing, so it's possible that the vendor has sent me the wrong fan; I'm following up with them.

Regarding the antenna stuck to the underside of the top of the case, I noticed today that there was a half-loop of slack in the wire connecting the antenna to the motherboard that was held together by a piece of tape. Removing the tape created enough slack in the wire to get the top of the case out of the way without having to unstick the antenna.